# remove zero value depend the zero value in another column R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have df with some in ID zero and some in an age in zero too. I want to remove any rows with Id zero if age < zero what is the best function in R

```
Id   | age
12   |  10
0    |  0 
0    |  5
```

need to be

```
Id   | age
12   |  10
0    |  0
```

remove rows with zero or `N/A` if the age bigger than zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

data <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(12,0,0),
    age = c(10,0,5)
  )

data %>% 
  filter(!(age > 0 & (is.na(id) | id == 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`

```
 subset(df1, !(id == 0 & age != 0))
```

-output

```
  id age
1 12  10
2  0   0
```